# how to show different bootstrap modals on a single page

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to open multiple modals on a single page but their ids are conflicting with each other. I got this code from bootstrap-4 documentation,

Modal 1 is works fine but modal 2 fails to work, I wants that both of them  to work separately

code:

modal1

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                  Add New
                </button>

  <!-- Modal Add Owner -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Owner</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('owner.store') }}">
        @csrf
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Add Owner Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="owner_name" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Owner Name">
          </div>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">
        </form>  
      </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

modal2:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                      <a href="{{ route('owner.show', $owner->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modalshow" data-target="#exampleModalshow">Show</a>
                    </button>


  <!-- Modal Show Owner-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalshow" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabe2" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">View Owner</h5>
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('owner.update', $owner->id) }}">
        @csrf
        @method('PATCH')
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Owner Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="owner_name" class="form-control" value="{{ $owner->owner_name }}">
          </div>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">
        </form>  
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: change button data-target same as modal id.

Answer (score 1):

Change `data-target` on the second modal button to match the modal id

```
<button data-target="#exampleModalshow">
   ... rest of the code
</button>
```

Comment: it still won't open the modal?